# Get Data from ExifInfo refered by different Types in XML-File

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I'm new to XML and have to change an existing xsl-sytelsheet.

The XML-File contains the following part per File (different ID):

```
<DbImage>
          <ID>2685986</ID>
          <FileSize>10,66 MB</FileSize>
          <FileDate>31-07-2017 10:19:02</FileDate>
          <FileCreated>31-07-2017 13:38:12</FileCreated>
          <FileLastAccessed>31-07-2017 13:53:52</FileLastAccessed>
          <Width>6000</Width>
          <Height>4000</Height>
          <Accessibility>Accessible</Accessibility>
          <MD5>111122223333</MD5>
          <ReportThumbnail>Thumbnails\000\c62e95c7-e595-4a77-8d20-ee2cd763af7d.jpg</ReportThumbnail>
          <ClassicationID>"XYZ"</ClassificationID>
          <SHA1>111122223333</SHA1>
          <LastClassificationDate>09-03-2021 10:35:27</LastClassificationDate>
          <LastClassifiedBy>USER</LastClassifiedBy>
          <ZZ40>0088AD4C58E1B3CE0023BE7F496DE1B0</ZZ40>
          <ExifInfo>
            <DbExif>
              <FriendlyExifName>AF Area Mode</FriendlyExifName>
              <Data>Wide</Data>
            </DbExif>
            <DbExif>
              <FriendlyExifName>AF Area Mode Setting</FriendlyExifName>
              <Data>Wide</Data>
            </DbExif>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <DbExif>
              <FriendlyExifName>Create Date</FriendlyExifName>
              <Data>2017-07-31 12:19:02</Data>
            </DbExif>
            <DbExif>
              <FriendlyExifName>Creative Style</FriendlyExifName>
               <Data>Standard</Data>
            </DbExif>
            ...
            ...
            ...

          </ExifInfo>
          <EvidenceDescription>1.21</EvidenceDescription>
          <FilePath>folder/Folder/Folder/Folder</FilePath>
          <FileName>File123.JPG</FileName>
          <ExifBrand>SONY</ExifBrand>
          <ExifModel>ILCA-68</ExifModel>
```

and many more DbExif-Lines. I can access all Data per Image (grouped by MD5) that are in the direct line (like FileDate, MD5, FileName, FilePath ...) but don't know how to get Data from a specific DbExif. For example the DbExif, where "FriendlyExifName = "Creat Date" and want to get the  of that. How can I do that?

I use

```
...
...

<table>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                    <table >
                    <tr>
                    <td>Dateiname:</td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('images-by-md5', MD5)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="FileName" /><br/> 
                                    
                    </xsl:for-each>             
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>Erstellt:</td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('images-by-md5', MD5)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="FileCreated" /><br/>                                  
                    </xsl:for-each> 
...
...
...
                                                        
                    <td>EXIF Creation Date:</td>
                    <td><xsl:for-each select="key('images-by-md5', MD5)">                   
                    <xsl:value-of select="**????????????**" /><br/>
                    </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                   
                   </td>
                   
                </tr>
                <br /><br /><br />
            
</table>
                
                
</xsl:for-each>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br /><br />
</xsl:for-each>
        
</xsl:if>
    
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is only a little part. At the ???????????? I need the Data of the "FriendlyExifName = "Creat Date" I mentioned.

I hope you can understand what I want :)

I tried  seperate for-each-Line for every DbExif
but did not work. Who can help?

Comment: This is difficult to follow because major parts of the code (e.g. the definition of the key) are missing. Your XML is also missing some end tags, and the `<ClassicationID>` start tag is misspelled(?). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) that the `<xsl:for-each select="key('images-by-md5', MD5)">` instruction puts you in the context of `DbImage`. From that context, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ExifInfo/DbExif[FriendlyExifName='Create Date']/Data" />
```

to extract the value you seek.

Note that in the XML snippet you posted, the value of `FriendlyExifName` is "Create Date", not "Creat Date".